# LaTeX - how do I force PDF page height/width?

Tags: pdf, paper-size

I am attempting to finish my LaTeX project, and I can't seem to get the PDF to compile to the right size no matter what I do.  In my .cls file I have this set:

```
\paperheight 11in
\paperwidth 8.5in
```

But no matter what I change it to, it compiles to about 8.25x11.7".

I can post my .cls files or anything else for that matter if someone knows hat I am doing 
Here is my .cls file: [usfmanus.cls](http://naspinski.net//file.axd?file=usfmanus.cls) - I am using BakomaTex Word for my editor.  When I compile my PDF, I am still getting strange dimensions.  I really appreciate this, thank you.

Comment: use the `geometry` package for such issues.

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The correct parameters to set are `\pdfpageheight` and `\pdfpagewidth`:

```
\pdfpageheight=11in
\pdfpagewidth=8.5in
```

However, this won't work in the "latex+dvips+ps2pdf" cycle. A code for both cases is

```
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\ifpdf
  \pdfpageheight=11in
  \pdfpagewidth=8.5in
\else
  \special{papersize=11in,8.5in}
\fi
```

The **geometry** way is better:

```
\usepackage[pass,letterpaper]{geometry}
```

or, if one wants a different paper size, (I'll use Letter paper sizes as example)

```
\usepackage[pass,paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11in]{geometry}
```

With the `pass` option, **geometry** won't change the class parameters for pagination, as it would do without it.

### Note for BakomaTeX

As far as I know, BakomaTeX doesn't use `pdflatex`, so the

```
\usepackage[pass,letterpaper]{geometry}
```

should be the one to follow.

Comment: Instead of 'paper' in `\pdfpaperheight` and `\pdfpaperwidth`, shouldn't it be 'page'?

Comment: @cyberSingularity They were changed in the meantime. Fixed.

Answer (score 26):

The `geometry` package might be useful here

```
\usepackage[paperheight=11in,paperwidth=8.5in]{geometry}
```

MWE:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[paperheight=11in,paperwidth=8.5in]{geometry}

    \begin{document}

    hello world

    \end{document}
```

Comment: When I compile, the finished pdf still looks like it's 8.5x11, even when I change the dimensions to paperheight=1in, paperwidth=8.5in. Why is this and how can I get a generated pdf that actually looks like it's 1 inch tall and 8.5 inches wide?

Answer (score 14):

you should probably use the [`geometry`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/geometry) package:

```
\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}
```

and compile with pdflatex. If you compile with dvips and ps2pdf, pay attention to the driver settings

Comment: How do I compile with pdflatex?  I am new at this and have been using BakomaTex Word.

Comment: I am not familiar with BakomaTex. Just open a command window in your working directory (where the mydocument.tex source is) and type at the prompt: C:\mydirectory>pdflatex mydocument.tex and the respective mydocument.pdf with proper size will be created.

Answer (score 8):

Try the following:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}
```

[Here](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf) you'll find the documentation for the geometry package.

Answer (score 3):

Here is method without using a package:

```
\pdfpagewidth 8.5in
\pdfpageheight 11in
```

Comment: BUt this does not work when i use `\includepdfmerge[fitpaper]{./test.pdf, 497}`  The page size is decided by the pdf page size due to fitpaper. Using fitpaper does not respect the `\pdfpagewidth=500pt \pdfpageheight=500pt` It changes the size of the paper. I am expecting `fitpaper` to fit into the 500pt x 500pt page size and later align it in the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

This might require the vmargin package, but using:

```
\setpapersize{USletter}
```

works too.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the layout package, you should call \usepackage{layout} after setting all your page parameters or \layout won't display correctly.

I just found out that if I include,
\usepackage{pdflscape}
It automatically parses the pdf page size correctly; even if you don't have any landscape pages.