# Geometry Package Not Working with Standalone Class

Tags: geometry, eps, standalone

Here is my TeX file (test.tex) I am trying to process (initially the TeX was successfully being processed on an Ubuntu 10.04 OS, but the server I am on was upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 and now things don't work as before):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{esint}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{xlop}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage[paperheight=\maxdimen]{geometry}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
\input{longdiv}
\pagestyle{empty}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
    $text here$
\end{document}
```

All of the packages seem to be included just fine, but in my log file I see the line `! Huge page cannot be shipped out.`, and my .eps file is not created.

This is the command I am running to convert my TeX:

```
latex --shell-escape --interaction=nonstopmode test.tex
```

If I comment out the `\usepackage[paperheight=\maxdimen]{geometry}` line, the TeX is successfully rendered.  I have tried other options for the geometry package, but nothing has worked so far.  Any suggestions for options to pass in, or perhaps a different package?

Comment: I guess that `\maxdimen` is not defined within `standalone` class. Replace the command by some value, for example, `297mm`.

Comment: Why do you want to have geometry with standalone? The idea of standalone is to change the size dynamically.

Comment: @Sigur: i was under the impression that `\maxdimen` was defined in geometry... either way, a static value still gave me an error.

@percusse: based on your comment, it seems like I don't need geometry? I had included the `\maxdimen` option in the first place because my LaTeX code was being cutoff at a certain height (most likely from geometry shrinking the image to 8.5x11" size?), so if it's not needed, then all the better..

Comment: You can use `geometry` with `standalone` and I have done this, but it is not the normal way to do it and you need to switch off some of `standalone`'s default functionality if you do so. However, looking at your preamble, I wonder if you are really misusing the class...

Comment: @Sigur `\maxdimen` is defined by the LaTeX kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr;

```
\usepackage[pass,paperheight=\maxdimen]{geometry}
```

Full Answer:

"With the `pass` option, `geometry` won't change the class parameters for pagination, as it would do without it." (As noted in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31973/latex-how-do-i-force-pdf-page-height-width) question here, the selected answer gave me the answer I needed.) After using the `pass` option, no more complaints about huge pages not being shipped out.