# How do you create a keyhole contour not centered at the origin?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've been trying to create a keyhole contour where the keyhole is a tiny circle in say, the first quadrant, and the main circle is still centered at the origin. I'm specifically not trying to create a keyhole contour where the keyhole is at the origin, and can't seem to find how to do that. I've been playing around with it for a while, but can't make anything work. Does anybody have any tips?

Thanks!

Edit: Here's what I'm trying to create: [image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please could you share what you have done so far in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).  This makes it easier both for us to understand what your issue is and provide solutions/suggestions.

Comment: Show us what you have been playing around!

Comment: Show us also what you wanted to achieve (a photo of an hand-written drawing could be enough), please!

Comment: @CarLaTeX I added a photo of what I'm going for (a poorly drawn one, I might add). I can't figure out how to make the keyhole look like that though, for every guide I've seen for drawing keyhole contours makes has the keyhole at the origin.

Comment: As you can see, Zarko has already answered. If his answer meets your needs, remember to upvote and accept it. Otherwise, please add a minimal working example to your question. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

[image]

In image is considered $sin{alpha} ~ \alpha$ (at small \alpha) and ratio between angles of hole in locus is about 8:

```
\documentclass[tikz,
               border=3mm,
               ]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, decorations.markings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Straight Barb,
decoration={markings,% switch on markings
            mark=between positions 0.2 and 0.8 step 0.25 with {\arrow[thick]{>}},
            mark=at position 0.86 with {\arrow[thick]{>}},
            mark=at position 0.98 with {\arrow[thick]{>}}
        }]
% curve
\draw[fill=gray!10, postaction={decorate}] 
            (47.5:2) arc (47.5:360:2   ) arc (0:42.5:2) 
       -- + (225:0.5) arc (25  :0  :0.25) arc(360:65:0.25) -- cycle;
% singularity
\fill[red]  (45:1.25) circle (1pt) node[inner sep=2pt,font=\footnotesize,right] {$a$};
% radius 
\draw[thick, ->] (0,0) -- node[sloped,above] {$r$} (330:2);
% coordinate axes
\draw[->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$\Re$};
\draw[->] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[above] {$\Im$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi @Zarko. This looks excellent! Sorry to be such a pain, but this isn't seeming to compile for me in my document. I created a new document for which it works, and I could just print that, but I'm curious as to why it doesn't work in the one I want it to. It's giving me an error at \end{tikzpicture} and saying "Huge page cannot be shipped out."

Comment: @DavidBowman See if this post can help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/225615/101651. Otherwise, please add a minimal working example that reproduces the error to your question (or, maybe better, ask another question with that MWE).

Comment: @DavidBowman, you didn't provide anything about what you try so far nor about your document. So, with not knowing preamble of your document and `\documentclass{...}` I can't say anything what is going wrong at you :(. Image size is 4cm x 4cm ...

Comment: @DavidBowman Maybe, `x` and `y` are set to non-default values. Then, it helps to reset them: `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1cm, y=1cm]`.