# Custom Papersize and Layoutsize (for Springer) using a documentclass (SVMult) and pdflatex

Tags: geometry, paper-size, sv-classes, svn-multi

I want a customized paper size, a customized text size and layout. Thus conforming to Springer's style requirements for scientific monographs which are different to conventional sizes like DIN A4.

- Text size: 117mm width and 191mm height
- Paper Size: 155mm width and 235mm height

Unfortunately, using Springer's SVMult template and pdflatex, the resulting pdf has the wrong size, namely A4. I guess this problem also exists for other styles with different text and paper layouts. The textsize is set in SVMult.

### How to customize papersize and layout using a custom documentclass (SVMult)  while using pdflatex?

- Is it possible to adapt the `svmult.cls` so that the correct paper size is generated?
- Can the package `geometry` be used while keeping SVMult settings?

### I tried the following:

Influenced by this question on [forcing pdf size](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31973/latex-how-do-i-force-pdf-page-height-width).

Using Custom Class

```
\documentclass[graybox]{svmult}
```

No Effect at all:

```
\pdfpagewidth = 155mm
\pdfpageheight = 235mm
```

Correct Paper size, wrong formatting, at least wrong left and right page margins:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={155mm,235mm}}
```

Using `pass` to keep SVMult settings thwarts papersize changes:

```
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\geometry{papersize={155mm,235mm}}
```

The problem prevails, using no other packages at all or using packages, among others hyperref.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass the options to `geometry` adding some other ones.

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} % because svmult uses non standard sizes

\documentclass{svmult}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
  verbose,
  papersize={155mm,235mm},
  textwidth=117mm,
  textheight=191mm,
  heightrounded, % <- I recommend this
  hratio=1:1,
  vratio=1:1,
}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\title*{My title}
\author{Jaße \inst{1}}
\institute{University \texttt{jasse@foo.bar}}
\maketitle

\abstract{\kant[1]}
\keywords{keywords}


\section{Introduction}

\kant

\end{document}
```

The `verbose` option is used just to check the results of the computations. In particular I get

```
* \paperwidth=441.01772pt
* \paperheight=668.63976pt
* \textwidth=332.89723pt
* \textheight=538.0pt
```

This corresponds, in millimeters, to

```
* \paperwidth=155mm
* \paperheight=235mm
* \textwidth=117mm
* \textheight=189.09mm
```

The difference in the text height is negligible, since `svmult` uses `\raggedbottom`, doing `heightrounded` is conceptually better, in my opinion.

[image]