# How can I correctly change page size to a non-letter size in pdflatex?

Tags: pdftex

The following example, based on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31976/24402), creates a pdf that is letter size.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[pass,paperwidth=2.5in,paperheight=7in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    Hello World
\end{document}
```

I also tried the following.

```
\documentclass{report}

%\usepackage[pass,paperwidth=2.5in,paperheight=7in]{geometry}
\pdfpaperheight=7in
\pdfpaperwidth=2.5in

\begin{document}
    Hello World
\end{document}
```

But it gives the following error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.4 \pdfpaperheight
                   =7in
? 
! Emergency stop.
l.4 \pdfpaperheight
                   =7in
```

What is the correct way to control page size for `pdflatex`?

Comment: it is called `\pdfpageheight`, I'd suggest using the `geometry` interface, then you don't got get adjusting other stuff.

Comment: @daleif, any hints on how to make the geometry interface work?

Comment: Geometry has an excellent manual and sets the pdfpage... variables automatically