# Resizing a standalone pdf-file with \geometry results not in the correct size or content is shifted

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, geometry, standalone

I want to externalize my tikz-picture in a standalone class. Because I am using relative measures as \textwidth I need my standalone-file to match excatly the dimensions as my main.tex is.

Looking [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31973/latex-how-do-i-force-pdf-page-height-width) the geometry package seems right for this. However, even with and without the 'pass' option the resulting picture has the wrong size or is being shifted inside the croppes area.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage[paperwidth=20cm]{geometry}  % add 'pass' stillt not work
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16, width= .8\textwidth}

\begin{document}
PaperWidth in [cm] \printinunitsof{cm}\prntlen{\paperwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot [] coordinates {(0,0) (1,2) (2,3)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
PaperWidth in [cm] \printinunitsof{cm}\prntlen{\paperwidth}
\end{document}
```

Without 'pass' picture not completely shown and wron size:

[image]

With 'pass' picture not completely shown but better and even smaller (80% of 21cm is not 8.8):

[image]

Comment: Remove the class option `tikz` and maybe add `crop=false` etc. By default `standalone` crops to the picture size. (It may even use `geometry`.) You've got conflicting instructions here so, unsurprisingly, things get messed up.

Comment: It would help to know what you want the result to be and how you're using this file. Are you compiling it and then including it as an external image or are you `\input`ting it in a main file?

Comment: I try deleting [tikz], this help a little, however when using this: \usepackage[pass,paperwidth=18cm]{geometry} and print out the textwidth it is saying still 21.59cm

Comment: In addition to @cfr 's comment, do you use the `externalize` library of `pgf-tikz` ?

Comment: I want to create the pictures inside the standalone file where I also use a precompiles preamble and for draft purposes just insert the .pdf in the main. At the end of the project I then delete the includegraphics and use \input of the pure standalonefile so all references etc. are correct. So to finalize the pictures in the standalone I need to use correct distances for example when using \textwidth as when plotting a graph with 'scale only axis' a difference in paperwidth result in a complete different plot in visual way so I just look for a way setting the standalone file to a fix textwidth

Comment: that commands like \textwidth works correct

Comment: @BambOo no I don't use the externalize function

Comment: Why do you replace`includegraphics` with `\input` calls, you have references **inside** the `tikzpicture` ?

Comment: In my main I loaded some packages I don't use in my standalone like microtype and other settings where I don't know exactly if they interfere with some fonts or something. So to make sure that all looks the same in the plots and pictures as in the main I recompile it at the end from the main which loaded these packages. More i sometomes use some \parencite or referneces to chapters in my main-file so I donÄt know if they will be placed correctly when just use the compiled version from the standalone class

Comment: Personnally I never use references inside figures, so I would not be the right person for this. Unfortunately, besides that, I do not really see what you want to achieve with your MWE

Comment: Why don't you just set the relevant width in the setting for PGF plots? You're hard-coding it anyway, so it isn't any less flexible. As long as it is only in the preamble, it won't affect the final version. I don't understand the obsession with setting `\textwidth`. But, if you really must, just set it. I wouldn't bother with `geometry ` etc. unless, of course, you want to see the plot as it will be on a full page. That would be different, obviously.

Comment: Additional remarks: `textwidth` is not the same as `paperwidth`. `standalone` uses `class=article` by default. Option `pass` disables all of the geometry options and calculations except `verbose` and `showframe`. If you know the value of the text width, then you can try `\setlength\textwidth{<length>}`.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment so my apologies in advance. Happy to delete if it is not relevant.

In general, when I want to have external plots, I follow this strategy.

I start with creating a `FigureHeader.tex` file containing set of parameter instructions

```
% some useful  packages
\usepackage{...}
....
% some useful libraries
\usetikzlibrary{...}
% Some personal styles/options
\tikzset{myaxis/.style={width=20cm,...}}
```

this way you can define a lot of parameters in the same parameter file, so if you have a lot of repeating graphics, it's easier to do this than to rewrite everything all the time.

Then in the  image file do

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\input{FigureHeader}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[myaxis]
             ...
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Then, in the main document, I simply input the figure with `\includegraphics{theimage.pdf}`

Comment: yes I am doing this nearly the same, using a precompiled file which contains all used packages for the graphics and a shared preamble for some style definitions so everyplot looks the same

Comment: Cool, so not totally irrelevant. What do you mean by _a precompiled file_ ?

Comment: I precompiled the static part of the preamble like loading the Tikz-packages etc following this manual: [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160712215709/http://www.howtotex.com:80/tips-tricks/faster-latex-part-iv-use-a-precompiled-preamble/)  so that i nearly receive a live preview (compiling of the picture does take about 2senconds now)