# Unable to change page dimensions (Lualatex)

Tags: geometry

I would like my document to be 12 by 18 inches. I try the following (recommended [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31973/latex-how-do-i-force-pdf-page-height-width)), compiling with Lualatex, and it seems to give a page which is still 8.5 by 11 inches.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pass,paperwidth=12in,paperheight=18in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

~

\end{document}
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `pass` argument which you also sneaked into the parameters of the geometry package.

See the documentation of the geometry package for `pass`

> disables all of the geometry options and calculations except verbose
>   and showframe. It is order-independent and can be used for checking
>   out the page layout of the documentclass, other packages and manual
>   settings without geometry.

Without it, everything works fine for me.

I added some lorem ipsum to see the difference with and without the geometry package (with it is 1 page and without it is 3 pages...)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=12in ,paperheight=18in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ligula arcu, vulputate et aliquet at, congue fringilla est. Aliquam efficitur sollicitudin lacus, in finibus neque tincidunt eget. Mauris pretium ante sem, sit amet sagittis quam elementum eget. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Cras at augue ac justo porta sodales. Suspendisse eleifend ipsum at sem mollis, sit amet ultricies ipsum volutpat. Nulla sit amet accumsan mauris. Fusce eget leo ac dolor ornare lobortis sit amet a eros. Mauris dapibus eu tortor et suscipit. Cras nulla eros, pellentesque vitae tincidunt et, faucibus sit amet justo. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Nullam et tortor faucibus, scelerisque tortor at, bibendum diam.

Sed posuere lacus non enim mattis, at maximus ante molestie. Ut ut bibendum eros. Integer consequat tortor a accumsan tempus. Duis accumsan feugiat eros, at elementum nunc sagittis quis. Maecenas varius risus ac est aliquet, id eleifend dui hendrerit. Nullam sed est at tortor egestas blandit. Phasellus quis leo sit amet est fermentum pellentesque eget ut lorem. Proin scelerisque sodales volutpat. Maecenas purus felis, consectetur non augue ac, aliquet consectetur metus. Duis vel dolor non risus hendrerit egestas. Vestibulum ornare ultricies sollicitudin. Sed vehicula dapibus metus et porttitor. Morbi in ipsum ut nisi dapibus aliquet. Ut vel nisl ac libero condimentum laoreet. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Curabitur suscipit nunc eget interdum porta.

Pellentesque quis mi in tellus auctor mattis eu sit amet massa. Proin posuere nibh sed vestibulum malesuada. Sed non diam gravida, luctus metus rutrum, pharetra erat. Curabitur vitae maximus magna, non eleifend arcu. Nullam eu metus augue. In ut risus facilisis lectus rhoncus porta quis nec felis. Morbi a enim non enim porttitor laoreet. In efficitur turpis facilisis, posuere urna ultricies, sodales arcu.

Nunc lobortis, erat in tempor fermentum, erat tortor faucibus metus, lacinia consequat eros libero id turpis. Pellentesque a magna erat. Suspendisse dignissim sagittis sapien, ac iaculis sem sodales id. Praesent nisi arcu, pellentesque maximus fermentum non, vestibulum non ex. Sed vitae volutpat nibh. Maecenas iaculis, urna et auctor euismod, urna lectus dignissim turpis, quis imperdiet ligula nunc vulputate lectus. Nulla vitae leo dui. Donec rutrum enim commodo pellentesque egestas. In bibendum augue nec diam laoreet, in cursus felis suscipit. Donec dolor sem, mollis non interdum nec, vestibulum eu lectus.

Quisque feugiat diam eget urna pulvinar, a tristique risus luctus. Integer quis nulla molestie, hendrerit turpis eu, convallis mauris. Mauris aliquam luctus volutpat. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vivamus condimentum eu felis a pretium. In a tristique est, eu tincidunt quam. Phasellus arcu libero, ultricies quis nibh nec, aliquet feugiat enim. Pellentesque eleifend nisi sit amet tellus facilisis, consectetur interdum tellus hendrerit. Vivamus felis leo, ullamcorper eu est rhoncus, viverra venenatis augue. Aliquam vestibulum, velit ut tincidunt mollis, tortor velit dapibus ante, nec egestas orci tortor feugiat est. Suspendisse potenti. Curabitur nisi tortor, scelerisque at velit nec, laoreet efficitur diam. Nunc sodales leo sit amet orci sollicitudin condimentum in non dolor. Mauris interdum mi erat, vel ultrices orci fermentum in.

Mauris auctor luctus varius. In mollis, erat at elementum volutpat, felis diam varius urna, interdum volutpat velit libero vel leo. Proin ipsum justo, rutrum eget blandit sit amet, molestie id dolor. Nullam tincidunt justo felis, sit amet ullamcorper ipsum lacinia condimentum. Ut neque nunc, bibendum sed ornare sit amet, lobortis at sapien. Pellentesque convallis quis augue sed imperdiet. Ut porttitor dui lectus, non laoreet mi congue sit amet. Sed venenatis finibus magna mollis elementum. Morbi vitae felis sed tortor luctus porta. In sit amet velit id tellus tincidunt fermentum. Maecenas volutpat est risus, eget consectetur justo vehicula ac. Cras vel fermentum tellus, vel faucibus arcu. Praesent ac risus libero. Suspendisse at convallis nunc. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae;

Etiam ac justo est. Nunc elementum, lacus quis euismod ultrices, nulla purus pretium leo, at facilisis metus massa et leo. Nunc eget justo est. Aliquam convallis augue quis vulputate porta. Donec posuere, odio eu aliquet viverra, risus dolor fringilla ante, sit amet bibendum lorem velit sed nunc. Phasellus quis vestibulum justo. Proin pellentesque sed leo a lobortis. Duis mollis eu nulla sed efficitur. Vivamus sollicitudin eros lobortis, imperdiet lectus nec, scelerisque sapien. Curabitur sollicitudin ipsum tellus, ut scelerisque ante imperdiet ullamcorper. Donec tempor vestibulum urna eu pellentesque. Praesent et accumsan lectus.

Quisque ligula diam, mattis in fringilla in, sollicitudin rutrum risus. Nulla feugiat ac purus ut condimentum. Nullam viverra nisi diam, semper lacinia ipsum condimentum sit amet. Nullam accumsan tempus est sed posuere. Praesent quis orci iaculis, facilisis nisi ut, malesuada ipsum. Curabitur vulputate odio diam, eu molestie velit commodo vel. Ut lacinia eu nisi ac sodales. Nulla justo metus, vulputate sit amet feugiat ut, cursus sit amet enim. Praesent sed arcu commodo, aliquam enim sed, porttitor est. Donec vitae bibendum erat, vel feugiat orci. Ut odio ligula, accumsan eget neque et, dignissim vestibulum ipsum.

Duis non arcu nisi. Donec non condimentum leo, quis accumsan eros. Donec rutrum quis leo nec finibus. Aliquam at mauris quis augue placerat tempus. Curabitur metus est, finibus at elit sed, tincidunt maximus arcu. Curabitur ut felis vitae odio eleifend volutpat id vitae augue. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut vel scelerisque tellus. Praesent dolor mauris, vulputate sed est at, iaculis iaculis odio.

Sed pharetra felis in bibendum fringilla. Morbi id viverra tortor, aliquam auctor odio. Cras ut nisi nec odio fringilla dapibus. Morbi consequat quam in interdum tristique. Vestibulum facilisis ligula non sem hendrerit feugiat. Suspendisse lobortis ornare molestie. Curabitur et bibendum purus. Vestibulum et erat non nibh auctor dignissim. Maecenas nec ultrices sapien. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Pellentesque vulputate enim in neque consequat interdum ut sed justo. Nulla at turpis turpis. Nunc eleifend iaculis sodales. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non est risus. Nullam vitae lacinia est.

Suspendisse quis magna dolor. Aenean sit amet dapibus magna, eget venenatis turpis. Morbi eros tellus, consequat a dictum ut, pretium eu massa. Nunc a rutrum diam. Donec et pharetra velit, aliquet faucibus quam. Phasellus sit amet velit auctor, venenatis tellus ac, hendrerit massa. Etiam a tortor rhoncus, congue velit vitae, vehicula elit.

Phasellus eu venenatis ligula, sit amet dictum erat. Vestibulum rhoncus libero quis tellus tempor semper quis at nisl. Donec consequat ultrices metus, eu euismod neque ullamcorper sit amet. Pellentesque porta mauris tempus, mattis justo vel, facilisis enim. Quisque vestibulum velit et turpis tempor elementum. Etiam sodales dui non mauris egestas pulvinar. Etiam tincidunt at tellus id finibus. Fusce semper faucibus nulla, ac pulvinar diam eleifend sed. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Integer ligula nunc, scelerisque a tellus at, finibus ultrices lectus. Aenean metus lectus, volutpat at nisi id, porttitor feugiat justo. Nullam accumsan ultrices feugiat. Etiam cursus dui et posuere eleifend.

Sed id commodo elit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse lobortis, justo et pharetra egestas, tellus lorem tristique magna, ut iaculis augue sem quis turpis. Sed eu malesuada turpis, id dapibus ligula. Nam vel justo quis lacus eleifend egestas. Maecenas finibus vulputate risus, sit amet varius ipsum. Vivamus quis risus ac velit ullamcorper viverra vel id nisl. Cras tempus nulla id lobortis commodo. Suspendisse ac enim sollicitudin, ornare ante eu, sollicitudin diam. Donec semper a dolor non vestibulum.

Vivamus vestibulum rhoncus venenatis. Fusce quis convallis magna. Duis rhoncus tempor turpis at faucibus. Nulla facilisi. Aenean a scelerisque turpis. Pellentesque at vehicula purus. Curabitur blandit purus nec volutpat lacinia. Cras nulla lorem, bibendum eu felis a, ullamcorper ornare leo. Fusce dapibus convallis ex vitae hendrerit. Vestibulum nec neque nec neque tempor pulvinar. Etiam luctus diam in commodo tempor. Integer porta eget mauris eu tempor. Suspendisse facilisis laoreet commodo. Vestibulum varius nisl et luctus porttitor. Nam urna velit, imperdiet eu scelerisque sit amet, vulputate eget sem. Quisque efficitur tortor vel augue placerat, ut placerat eros rutrum.

Donec blandit egestas efficitur. Praesent sollicitudin lacus dui, ac fermentum ipsum bibendum non. In ipsum augue, fermentum non faucibus sed, semper id orci. Cras mattis cursus fringilla. Quisque ligula leo, rhoncus eget turpis eu, bibendum ultricies lectus. Sed maximus eros a orci commodo iaculis. Duis sodales eleifend semper. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure how "pass" snuck in. It must have been a bad case of copy-paste.

Comment: Could you help me with margins also? This does nothing: `\usepackage[paperwidth=12in,paperheight=18in,left=.5in,right=.5in]{geometry}
`

Comment: @Erewhon does it produce an error? works like a charm for me

Comment: You are right. The left, right parameters do seem to work as intended. I am still having some difficulties but I think my next question should be posted separately. Thanks again for all of your help.